# concatenate javascript to URL

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Following is the URL I am having I want to change the href tag with the URL of the page where this code is placed, that I can get using "window.location.href" but I want to concatenate it to URL at the place of href tag, I am using asp.net

```
<iframe src="http://www.XYZ.com/plugins/like.php?href=<?php echo rawurlencode(get_permalink()); ?>&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=550&amp;action=like&amp;font=segoe+ui&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=80" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:550px; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

I want to replace this `href=<?php echo rawurlencode(get_permalink()); ?>` with the current page's url, how can I achieve this please let me know?

Comment: You are using ASP.NET, and yet have PHP tag encoding. Which is it?

Comment: basically, it's a PHP plug in of face book, that XYZ url is face book where i want to add my asp.net page link where this button will be placed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood your question properly, you should be able to replace `href=<?php echo rawurlencode(get_permalink()); ?>` with:

```
href=<%= Request.Url.AbsoluteUri %>
```

Although to guard against XSS you could do a lot worse than download the [AntiXss library](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=F4CD231B-7E06-445B-BEC7-343E5884E651) and make sure you encode the URL you're outputting:

```
href=<%= AntiXss.HtmlAttributeEncode(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri) %>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   // set the param
   var href="<?php echo rawurlencode(get_permalink()); ?>";
   // get current location
   var current_location = window.location.href;
   // set the source of the iframe
   document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].src = current_location + '&href=' + href;
</script>
```

Comment: your solution is amazing too.